# Pausar videos no visibles

Tags: javascript, video, videojs

Qué tal. 
Necesito ayuda para pausar los videos que salen de la vista al dar scroll.

Ya eh avanzado bastante y mi código es ligero, lo adjunto por si a alguien le sirve.

Donde me encuentro atorado es en la parte de la altura, es decir el video comienza a reproducirse justo cuando toca la parte superior de la pantalla pero requiero que se reproduzca unos 130px más abajo.

El código que utilizo es:

```js
var vids = document.getElementsByClassName('_makina'); 

for (var i = vids.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
 //pause all the videos by default
 vids[i].pause();
}

window.onscroll = autoplay;

function autoplay(){
    for (var i = vids.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var currentYpos = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if ( currentYpos >= vids[i].offsetTop && currentYpos <= vids[i].offsetTop + vids[i].offsetHeight ) {
   vids[i].play();
  }else{
   vids[i].pause();
  }
 }
}
```

```css
.space {
  height: 750px;
  background-color:#252525;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
}

.space2 {
  height: 750px;
  background-color:#151515;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
}

.space3 {
  height: 750px;
  background-color:#dc0031;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="space"><h3><br><br><br>Desplazate hacia abajo</h3></div>

<video id="myVid" width="100%" autoplay preload class="_makina">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="https://makina.com.mx/videos/847692459.mp4" >
</video>

<div class="space2"><br><br><br><h3>Sigue más abajo</h3></div>

<video id="myVid" width="100%" autoplay preload class="_makina">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://makina.com.mx/videos/847692459.mp4" >
</video>

<div class="space3"><br><br><br><h3>Aquí acabamos</h3></div>
```

Para que se den una idea les dejo el link en el que estoy trabajando, me pidieron algo muy, muy , muy parecido a FB.

** *OJO: no es spam, en cuanto encontremos la solución lo quitaré. **

URL:  https://makina.com.mx/new2/

Por eso necesito que se reproduzca unos cuantos pixeles más abajo para que la barra azul no lo tape.

Llevo 2 días sin poder avanzar :(

Saludos y de antemano Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicado en el mismo código, espero te sirva..

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", finder);

function finder(){
 var vid = document.getElementById("midiv"),
     text = document.getElementById("status");
  document.addEventListener("scroll", analyzer);
 
  function analyzer(){
     var w = vid.offsetWidth,
     scrolled = vid.getBoundingClientRect(),
     eq = w - Math.abs(scrolled.top); // Con esto podrás saber que porción del div se está viendo, ya que, se le resta al tamaño total del div INCLUYENDO BORDES con offsetWidth, y getBoundingClientRect me devuelve la position relativa del elemento, con relación a lo VISIBLE, osea si moviste 30 px hacia abajo , este mostrará -30, por eso también el uso de Math.abs ( valor absoluto ) y por qué -30 ? porque las coordenadas comienzan en (0,0) , en el borde superior izquierdo, por eso también al body lo puse con un margin y un padding de 0( en el css), para que no altere esto. 

     
     if(eq === w)  text.innerHTML =                 "Reproduciendose"; // 
     else  text.innerHTML = "Pausado..";
  }
}

// Esto es sólo para generar <br> y así tener la barra, NO TOMAR EN CUENTA.-
for(var i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++ ) {
var e = document.createElement("br"); document.body.appendChild(e);
}
```

```css
#midiv {
width: 200px;height:200px;border:2px solid black;
}
body, html {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#status {
 position: relative; 
 top: 45%;
 left: 23%;
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="midiv">
<i id="status">Reproduciendose</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, fijate si te sirve este plugin de jquery, https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport

el codigo te deberia quedar algo asi:

`$('video').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":in-viewport")) {
        $(this)[0].play();
    } else {
        $(this)[0].pause();
    }
})`